# how to create exe for php standalone application?

Tags: php, batch-file

> How to create .exe for php  standalone application?

I have created application that runs on localhost.This application is developed for local use.so i have look up for that type of setup that:

1.create php setup,
2.create shortcut,
3.install apache and mysql and start mysql and apache server,
4.onclick shortcut,project run in browser

> **LATER UPDATE**
>   Is it good way to create batch file that done upper things and is it possible?
>   if possible, please suggest some examples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Not possible.

Long answer: It depends.

You could install a web- and database server on his machine (or create an installer that does it) and run the application locally on his machine.

or

You keep the application on a server and just provide a launcher that opens his browser and points it to the URL of the application.

It might be a good idea to switch to SQLite instead of MySQL but depending on how your application is written it might require a lot of code and SQL Query changes.

[PHP Desktop](http://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/) which allows you to create desktop apps in the same way as you build websites with php/html/js.

The convenient solution is not to convert the website to .exe. I think it will be better if you have portable [server/php/mysql](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp) and make the website work from a usb or CD with autorun.